# How to view features list and their importance in TokenNameFinder model in OpenNLP

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I have trained `TokenNameFinder` of OpenNLP which outputs **.bin** file. Now I need to list features with their importance.

I read code of `TokenNameFinder` and `NameFinderME` but could not find a way to print features. Is their any way to list all features of model along with their importance ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out a way to list features. Function `getDataStructures()` of `AbstractModel` class returns a array of `Object` instances. Second element of this array is a `Map<String, Integer>` whose keys are combination of features and their values. Following is the code snippet for accessing features and their values:

```
AbstractModel maxModel =  model.getArtifact("nameFinder.model");
                Object[] obj = maxModel.getDataStructures();

                if(obj!=null) {
                    Map<String, Integer> pmap = (HashMap<String, Integer>) obj[1];
                    Set<String> keySet = pmap.keySet();
                    for(String key: keySet) {
                        System.out.println(key +" **** "+ pmap.get(key));
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("obj is null." );
                }
```